# Bigcommerce Stencil - How to find top-level category inside category each

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new to stencil and I am trying to get the top-level category when on a non-top-level category page. I am looking to loop through the categories but only print the items listed below the top-level. Here is what I am using that works if I am on a top-level page but doesnt if I am on a subcategory page.

```
{{#each categories}}
            {{#if name '===' ../category.name}}
              <li class="parent {{#if children}}has-children tier-dropdown{{/if}}">
                <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
                {{#if children}}
                  <ul class="children">
                    <li class="parent-all"><a href="{{url}}">{{lang 'common.navigation_all'}} {{name}}</a></li>
                    {{#each children}}
                      <li>
                        <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
                        {{#if children}}
                          <ul class="children2">
                            <li class="parent-all"><a href="{{url}}">{{lang 'common.navigation_all'}} {{name}}</a></li>
                            {{#each children}}
                                <li {{#if children}}class="tier-dropdown"{{/if}}>
                                    <a {{#if children}}class="tier-toggle"{{/if}} href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
                                    {{#if children}}
                                        <ul class="tier-panel">
                                            <li class="parent-all"><a href="{{url}}">{{lang 'common.navigation_all'}} {{name}}</a></li>
                                            {{#each children}}
                                                <li {{#if children}}class="tier-dropdown"{{/if}}>
                                                    <a {{#if children}}class="tier-toggle"{{/if}} href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
                                                    {{#if children}}
                                                        <ul class="tier-panel">
                                                            <li class="parent-all"><a href="{{url}}">{{lang 'common.navigation_all'}} {{name}}</a></li>
                                                            {{#each children}}
                                                                {{> components/common/site-navigation-submenus}}
                                                            {{/each}}
                                                        </ul>
                                                    {{/if}}
                                                </li>
                                            {{/each}}
                                        </ul>
                                    {{/if}}
                                </li>
                            {{/each}}
                          </ul>
                        {{/if}}
                      </li>
                    {{/each}}
                  </ul>
                {{/if}}
              </li>
             {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
```

The main point of emphasis is line 2 as that if statement needs to always point to the top-level category even when on a subcategory page.

I have though about using breadcrumbs but cant come up with a way to use that inside the categories each loop.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pure Stencil/Handlebars.js solution for this. You need to be able to do a recursive upward search of the parent categories which BigCommerce doesn't have a helper for. The best solution is to restyle or add items to the list during page load.

You can either use the page url, depending on the structure of your URLs, or breadcrumbs as you mentioned.

TL;DR you need javascript.

Comment: TL;DR you need javascript is so appropriate here.